# Versioning In Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

We have a `user` model and `feature` model:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :user_features
   has_many :features, through: :user_features
end

#app/models/user_feature.rb
Class UserFeature < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :feature
end

#app/models/feature.rb
Class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :user_features
   has_many :users, through: :user_features
end
```

Features can be added and removed from a user's account

The typical way to do this will be to `add` / `remove` records from the `user_features` collection. However, we wanted to store a "history" of all the features a user has added / removed from their account over time

---

My question is: `how would I store the user_features & indicate which features have been added & which removed?`

It's very similar to versioning I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an active field to your UserFeatures model and scope it in your user model (not tested):

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :user_features
   has_many :features, through: :user_features

   has_many :active_user_features, -> { where(active: true) }, class_name: 'UserFeature'
   has_many :active_features, through: :active_user_features
end
```

For deletion of packages, you should just set the active field to false

Answer (score 2):

[PaperTrail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) works great for versioning / tracking the history of model changes and also supports [has_many :through](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#has-many-through-associations) associations.

Check out the docs and see if it's what you're looking for or if it's too much for your purposes.